# vba swapping two row ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to swap two rows with vba.

I have this code:

```
Sub copyrow()
    Dim temp1 As Range, temp2 As Range, x As Variant
    Set temp1 = Range("F4:U4")
    Set temp2 = Range("F6:U6")

    x = temp1
    temp1 = temp2
    temp2 = x
End Sub
```

temp2 gets filled with temp1 which is correct, but somehow temp1 ends up empty? Not sure where I've gone wrong

Comment: Apologies, try x As Variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `.Value`:

```
x = temp1.Value
temp1.Value = temp2.Value
temp2.Value = x
```